# How do you listen for mouse paste done in a TextField using JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

Copy text into your clipboard, right click text field and press "paste", is there a way how to listen when paste was clicked? Or rather that input text in the field changed after something was pasted this way. Because these do not work in this particular case:

```
setOnKeyReleased()
setOnInputMethodTextChanged()
```

Comment: Isn't it enough just to check whether the text was changed?

Comment: You could do an "ugly" solution. Something like this: When `TextField` is right clicked, listen for the `TextField` text to change. When it changes the first time after the right click has been made (and no key has been pressed, to make sure the text was pasted), check if the new text is the same as the String in the OS clipboard. Would this be sufficient? If so, I could present an example of this to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "paste" functionality is implemented in the `TextInputControl` superclass of `TextField` in [`public void paste()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#paste--). So, while it's not really an event-driven or MVC approach, you can react to a "paste" action (whether it's invoked by mouse or keyboard shortcut, typically ctrl-V) by overriding this method:

```
TextField tf = new TextField() {
    @Override
    public void paste() {
        super.paste();
        System.out.println("text pasted in");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just listen to text property changes.
example with a search text field:

```
tf_search.textProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                onSearch();
            });
```

The other approach would be to override the appropriate method using Clipboard.

```
 TextField tf = new TextField() {
            @Override
            public void paste() {
                Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
                if (clipboard.hasString()) {
                    replaceSelection(clipboard.getString());
                }
            }
        };
```