# How to override TextField functionality for specific class?

Tags: events, javafx, overriding

I have `KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED` on my `TextField`s. If user pastes data with keyboard shortcut, event gets triggered. But it doesn't work if user pastes with right click on mouse. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762158/how-do-you-listen-for-mouse-paste-done-in-a-textfield-using-javafx) that solves this issue. But I have many `TextField`s, can I `override` method for all `TextField`s at once, but only for current class I'm working on?

Comment: Have you tried checking if the parent class of your Textfield is matching that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class NewTextField extends TextField {
     @Override
    public void paste() {
        super.paste();
        System.out.println("text pasted in");
    }
}
```

Use NewTextField as the textfield you want to have your paste feature.

Comment: And what can I do with existing `TextField` that are originally there from .fxml file?

Comment: @Alyona I would assume the intention is to replace `<TextField>` with `<NewTextField>` whenever you need the additional functionality.

Comment: I add through code only few `TextField`, most of them are placed in .fxml.

Comment: @Alyona Yes, exactly, that's what I meant. Use `<NewTextField>` in your FXML instead of `<TextField>`.