# How to open fxml in Scene Builder that has custom elements?

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Based on answer I received in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961079/how-to-override-textfield-functionality-for-specific-class) I replaced all `TextFields` with `TextFieldPasteListener` in my `fxml` file. Problem is, I can no longer open my `fxml` in Scene Builder. This is error I get:

```
java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
/C:/Users/aljona.gvozdeva/Documents/workspace/AccountingApp/src/home/accounting/view/RegistrationForm.fxml
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:92)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:82)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:97)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2384)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:664)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:385)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:634)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.access$200(SceneBuilderApp.java:84)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp$1.invalidated(SceneBuilderApp.java:496)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.UserLibrary.lambda$updateFirstExplorationCompleted$7(UserLibrary.java:324)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/aljona.gvozdeva/Documents/workspace/AccountingApp/src/home/accounting/view/RegistrationForm.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2848)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2661)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:89)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: home.accounting.controller.TextFieldPasteListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
    ... 27 more
```

I imported `TextFieldPasteListener` in my `fxml` file:

```
<?import home.accounting.controller.TextFieldPasteListener?>
```

This is my `TextFieldPasteListener` class:

```
import com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent;
import com.sun.glass.ui.Robot;

import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class TextFieldPasteListener extends TextField {
    @Override
   public void paste() {
       super.paste();
       try {
           Robot robot = com.sun.glass.ui.Application.GetApplication().createRobot();
           robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

Is there any way I can edit my `fxml` with Scene Builder after I added custom elements?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063792/adding-a-custom-component-to-scenebuilder-2-0

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm a bit new in this, how can I bundle my custom class?

Comment: Thank you, I did everything and it works now